# Radio Button Click with Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have been working on a web scraping script that gets past the login page but I can't find a way to get this radio button selected as the script attempts to login.
Here's the button:

```
<input type="radio" name="UserType" id="UserType" value="PARENTSWEB-PARENT" tabindex="4">
```

When it is clicked it looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="UserType" id="UserType" value="PARENTSWEB-PARENT" tabindex="4" checked="checked">
```

I am using a dictionary to submit the username and password but not sure how to add the button functionality into it.
Dict:

```
payload={
                'username':USERNAME,
                'password':PASSWORD,
                'DistrictCode':DistCode,
                'PARENTSWEB-STUDENT':'checked'
        }
```

I am using the requests library and lxml to submit and look at the data. But if there is a better library or another one I can also use I'm open to anything.

Comment: `payload` should submit name-value pairs. So the last item should be 'UserType': 'PARENTSWEB-PARENT'. And you're sure you're submitting all of the hidden items too, eh?

Comment: @Tommy, This is not how thing works. To get an answer you should provide the "Query string parameter" along with "Form Data" if exists.

Comment: @Topto: Tommy asked about how to submit radio button data, *not* about the whole business of submitting data from a form. What I told him does the job.

Comment: check out [roboborser](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser)